# How to set data using Nest REST API?

Tags: nest-api

I have tried to set the target temperature the following script and it returns {"error":"Invalid content sent"}.  How can I set the target temperature using the REST API?

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA='{"devices":{"thermostats":{"DEVICE_ID":{"target_temperature_f":75}}}'

curl --cacert curl-ca-bundle.crt -L -X PUT --data $DATA "https://developer-api.nest.com/?auth=ACCESS_CODE"
```

Note that I redacted the actual device id and access code.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `Content-Type` header to tell the API service that it's JSON data that's being sent? `-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: I just tried it.  I updated the command in the question to reflect the latest command I have tried.  I am still getting an error.

Comment: I got it to work using your suggestion.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA='{"target_temperature_f":76}'

curl --cacert curl-ca-bundle.crt -v -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/DEVICE_ID?auth=ACCESS_CODE" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d DATA
```